# JSP not working on Apple Macintosh under Oracle Weblogic web server

Tags: oracle, jsp, safari, weblogic

I have the following jsp code that I use in an Oracle Applications menu function item in order to redirect to a url in a new window when the Oracle Applications menu item is clicked.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<script>
<%
out.println("var url=\"" + request.getParameter("URL").trim() + "\";");
%>

var load = window.open(url,"_blank","directories=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes");

history.go(-1);
</script>
```

This works fine on all browsers for Windows machines, however users with Safari on Apple Macintosh who click the link finds that nothing happens except a menu refresh.

I'm not sure whether this relates to the fact that the Oracle Weblogic web server does not have anything in its mimemappings.properties mime type config file that relates to serving jsp. I also don't seem to be able to find out what the mime type is for jsp. Google returns nothing for application/jsp or jspc (not sure what the compiled extension is).

Just had a thought that it might be a popup blocker.

Anyone have any other ideas or insights with regards to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the popup blocker.